# How to I create an inverted border like this?

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M1Mj.png) I'm able to achieve the top right border radius as per this design but for the left border I'm a bit confused.

```
.inverted-border-radius::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 38px;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #d6dcea;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(
    circle 10px at 0 0,
    transparent 0,
    transparent 20px,
    black 21px
  );
  box-shadow: 0 -25px 0 0 #f66969;
}
```

This is css that I'm using. I know that some changes on radial-gradient will do the trick but getting really confused here.

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: Could you please share you HTML as well

Comment: it seems your are over-complicating a simple task. Your image show that the first section has a border radius at the bottom. Why trying an invert border on the second one

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know that this is not an elegant solution but I don't have a other way around here. I tried to position the top <div> over the footer but it's not coming well together.

Comment: I agree with @TemaniAfif, I'd add the border radius to the first section, paired with a negative  `margin-botom` value and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

apply `border-bottom`

```css
.card {
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;


border: 1px solid #dfe2e6;
border-bottom: 5px solid #2091bd;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    
</div>
```